# How to define a file-scope symbol in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In C#, the `#define` directive defines a symbol, for example, the following line defines a symbol "DEBUG":

```
#define DEBUG
```

the scope of this symbol is the file in which it is defined.

In C++, a pre-processing symbol (/D "DEBUG") can be defined to get the same effect. But /D is a project-wide setting switch.

My question is, how to define a symbol that is local to a file in C++?

Comment: "In C++, a preprocessing symbol (/D "DEBUG")... project defined switch".  That's not a general C++ thing as you imply, rather it's specific to the compiler and built tools in use.  Yours appear to be MSVC++.  Anyway, `#define`'s are discouraged when other C++ mechanisms are equally applicable (google the C++ FAQ if unsure why), and OrbWeaver's answer documents the best alternative....

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my wrong assumption. I guess I asked the question in the wrong way. What I want to do is defining a "DEBUG" symbol that can be tested by the #ifdef directive, if it is defined, I will print the diagnostic message to the console. And I then notice that in C++, the #define directive basically do text replacement, like "#define MAXVALUE 99". If I use "#define DEBUG" at the top of my cpp file, then later "#ifdef DEBUG" still evaluated to false... so i think "#define DEBUG" does not do the thing i expect. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh, I find why "#ifdef DEBUG" is still evalated to false right after "#define DEBUG", it is get messed with the project settings， and now it works as expected.  Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 7):

`#define` in C and C++ is available, but it does not create a symbol, it creates a pre-processor macro, which is essentially a text replacement operation which takes place before the compiler even sees the source file.

The usual way to create a file-local symbol in a C++ file is to use an anonymous namespace, e.g.

```
namespace 
{
    const int SOME_LOCAL_INT = 3;
    const std::string SOME_LOCAL_STRING("Blah");
}
```

The use of an anonymous namespace ensures that the symbol is not visible outside of the compilation unit in which it is defined. Note however that if you define an anonymous namespace inside a header file, a copy of the symbols contained within will be accessible inside all C++ files which include that header file, so it is best to put the anonymous namespace inside a .cpp file to ensure that they are indeed local.

Comment: the same applies for static global members, without namespaces

Comment: *If you define an anonymous namespace inside a header file, the symbols contained within will be accessible inside all C++ files which include that header file*. That is not exactly true: different versions of the same identifiers will be available. Each translation unit will have it's own `SOME_LOCAL_INT`, that will be local to that translation unit. This is important in the case of non constants, as modifying a variable inside the unnamed namespace will not be seen in code from other translation units.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **necessarily** use `#define` in a header for symbol to be local in that header, then use as below:

```
//file.h
#define DEBUG
//... code
#undef DEBUG // clearing the symbol
```

`#undef` will undefined the previously defined `DEBUG`. So if you `#include` this `file.h` anywhere, it won't have any effect of `DEBUG` as it's just local to `file.h`.